# g++-4.3 cannot find in qt5.8 under linux

Tags: linux, qt, g++, openmesh

I had install g++ latest version, but the Qt5.8 cannot find g++-4.3 just like ":-1: error: g++-4.3: Command not found" could you help me? This project is the first tutorial of openmesh examples

Comment: My g++ version is 6.2.0. g++ 4.3 was released in March 2008.

Comment: @user258532 some linux distros are really behind on compiler versions, they basically stick to what was available back when they were released and ever update, as that would require updating the whole OS.

Answer (score 1):

Qt 5.8 doesn't support such an old GCC version. You should try at least 4.8.2.

Comment: I have installed all about  g++-4.9 , but this problem is still here.  Maybe the problem is that the least openmesh should g++-4.3? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I don't know about openmesh, but it might be helpful if you post screenshots of your Qt Creator build settings - compilers, qt versions, kits...